# Get coloured link borders back!

Tags: hyperref, color

I recognise I'm in the minority but I actually like having coloured borders around links as opposed to having the links themselves coloured. However the following command fails to bring sexy back:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, pdfborder={1 0 0}}
```

Has this functionality simply been removed? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Colored borders around links are still (current version: 6.86b) the default behaviour of `hyperref`. If you remove the `\hypersetup` line completely as shown in the following example, you should get the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{section}\label{section-label}
text \ref{section-label}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To influence the width of the border you can use the third digit of `pdfborder` . In the example you showed, you have set the width to be 0 pt.

Answer (score 3):

The default settings get you the colored link annotation boxes, see leandriis' [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415164/16967).

The values for option `pdfborder` are described in the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html):

> An array specifying the characteristics of the annotation’s border.
>   The border is specified as a rounded rectangle.
>
> In PDF 1.0, the array consists of three numbers defining the
>   horizontal corner radius, vertical corner radius, and border width,
>   all in default user space units. If the corner radii are 0, the border
>   has square (not rounded) corners; if the border width is 0, no border
>   is drawn. (See implementation note 81 in Appendix H.)
>
> In PDF 1.1, the array may have a fourth element, an optional dash
>   array defining a pattern of dashes and gaps to be used in drawing the
>   border. The dash array is specified in the same format as in the line
>   dash pattern parameter of the graphics state (see “Line Dash Pattern”
>   on page 217). For example, a **Border** value of `[0 0 1 [3 2]]`
>   specifies a border 1 unit wide, with square corners, drawn with 3-unit
>   dashes alternating with 2-unit gaps. Note that no dash phase is
>   specified; the phase is assumed to be 0. (See implementation note 82
>   in Appendix H.)
>
> ***Note:** In PDF 1.2 or later, this entry may be ignored in favor
>   of the **BS** entry (see above); see implementation note 82 in
>   Appendix H.*
>
> Default value: `[0 0 1]`.

This is also `hyperref`'s  default: `pdfborder={0 0 1}`.

With `pdfborder={1 0 0}`, the line width (third element) is zero and the borders vanish.

Comment: Ok thanks for your efforts but this doesn't work. Here is the entire preamble - perhaps there is a conflict. I am using ShareLatex and compiling with pdf latex.
`\documentclass{article}[11pt]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{legalpaper, portrait, margin=1in}




\title{\textbf{Data and Insight Training}}
\author{Thomas Bishop}
\date{February 2018}

\begin{document}`

Comment: @user63394 Make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), add it to your question; describe, how you compile the document (which TeX compiler, output mode, drivers, ...); check the `.log` file for the `hyperref` driver and add it to the description. Also, `hyperref` uses a configuration file `hyperref.cfg`, check the location of the file in the `.log` file and add it to the question as well, especially if this file is not a standard configuration file of a recent standard TeX distribution.